# F# Convert string to Discriminated Union with complex args

Tags: f#

Im trying to convert a `string` to a DU in F#. The DU cases have arguments that are quite complex. Is there a way to create the union case using `FSharpType.GetUnionCases` and `FSharpValue.MakeUnion` without passing in an argument for the case (creating the arguments and adding them into `MakeUnion` is not an option as they are way too complex)? My use-case is to basically match on the DU with no need of the arguments themselves. Is this possible? or is there another way to do this without using the `FSharp.Reflection` library?

eg:

```
type SomeUnion = 
| SomeUnionCase1 of SomeVeryComplexType
| SomeUnionCase2 of SomeOtherVeryComplexType


// some logic to convert string "SomeUnionCase1" to a DU case

// then match on it like so

match convertedDU with
| SomeUnionCase1 _ -> //do something with case 1
| SomeUnionCase2 _ -> //do something with case 2
```

Comment: Can you explain what you would do with one of the cases without having its data? It sounds more like a plain enum than a DU.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a DU case name should not change your app's behaviour. Renaming a case should be a safe refactoring.

The fact that you want to convert a string to the DU case indicates that you are storing string data based on the DU case name. It is very tempting to do this in F# but I strongly advise against it. See this [blog post](https://www.compositional-it.com/news-blog/dont-use-tostring-on-discriminated-unions-in-f/) for more reasons (I wrote it).

If I'm wrong in assuming that you're converting the DU case into a string then I would recommend you solve the problem in the manual and boring way for similar reasons:

```
match text with
| "SomeUnionCase1" -> SomeUnionCase1 ...
| "SomeUnionCase2" -> SomeUnionCase2 ...
```